# Add javascript typing timer dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

So I have an input box:

**HTML**

```
<input id="equation1" name="equation1" type="text"/>
```

And I have a timer that performs a function when the user stops typing in the input box:

**JavaScript**

```
var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 300;

$('#equation1').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(submitEquation, doneTypingInterval);
});

$('#equation1').keydown(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});
```

And I have a javascript function to make more input fields

**JavaScript**

```
function addEquation() {
    counter += 1;

    var newEquation = document.getElementById("equation1").cloneNode(true);
    newEquation.id = ("equation" + counter);

    newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.id = ("new" + counter);
    thing = "new" + counter;

    document.getElementById("new").appendChild(newdiv);
    newEquation.setAttribute('name', 'equation' + counter);
    document.getElementById(thing).appendChild(document.createTextNode("Equation" + counter + ": "));
    document.getElementById(thing).appendChild(newEquation);
}
```

and all this works fine. The question is how do I create a new typing timer to the new input box created?

Comment: IDs should be unique ! If you're creating a new element with a new ID, you need to attach the event again to the new ID.

Comment: @user381824 you'are biding the event to the first ID only !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abstract your keydown logic into a function, ex:

```
function bind_equation_key(id) {
    // where id is "equation1", "equation2", etc
    $('#'+id).keyup(function() {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        typingTimer = setTimeout(submitEquation, doneTypingInterval);
    });

    $('#'+id).keydown(function(){
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    });
}
```

And then call that on each of your new inputs with their id (which seems to be `"new" + counter`, though you may want it to be `"equation" + counter` for uniformity.

Just make sure to clean up your timer for the previous input when you create a new one.

Comment: How would you call the function? onChange isn't the same as keyup and keydown. I want submitEquation called anytime any of the input boxes are changed

Comment: It can be called with `bind_equation_key(new_id)` where `new_id` is the id of the new element you've created. If you want it to constantly submit for all inputs then do not clean them all up after you bind. This can be done at the end of your `addEquation` function. If it's a SPA then clean it up when you nav away.